# Add a character to end of every line in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I've a VBA code, which takes values from excel spreadsheet and imports them into a txt file in a certain view. What I need is to add a character "||" at the end of every row in the output file, but since I'm very new to coding, don't find the right "code wording".

Current code:

```
Sub OutputToTextFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim FileName As String, LineText As String
    Dim MyRange As Range, i, j
    
    FileName = "C:\data\output.txt"
    
    Open FileName For Output As #1
    
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:G20")
    For i = 1 To MyRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To MyRange.Columns.Count
            LineText = IIf(j = 1, "", LineText & " | ") & MyRange.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, LineText
    Next i

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Current output (single example only):

```txt
IBAN311 | Apple | IBAN123123 | BIC | BGN | IBAN311 | INV-12343
```

What I need is to have an additional "||" character after the "INV-12343" and same for every row in the range. How can I add that in the above code?

Comment: `Print #1, LineText & "||"`

Comment: Do you want it separated by `" | "`? Or add it joined to the last element? Something as "INV-12343||"?

Comment: exactly = "INV-12343||". This is what I'm aiming at - not separate all elements in every row by "||", but just adding it once at the end of every row, but still haven't found the right way to do it.